# Migrate data in mongodb from old schema to new schema via sailsjs

Tags: mongodb, migration, sails.js, sails-mongo

I want to migrate the schema of my models. I wanted to try to do so with the "migrate: alter" command in my env file.
The problem seems to be that on default the startup script will run in production mode which automatically uses "migrate: safe".
I´ve tried changing the "migrate" attribute to alter in die production.js file which does not take effect. Also I tried to set the environment variable to development but it will still start in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have simply installed sailsjs globally with npm, you can try cli command,\

```
sails migrate
```

to migrate the database. This is confirmed by sailsjs on [twitter](https://twitter.com/sailsjs/status/1127217448997019649).